# Скорость загрузки сайта на cms DataLife Engine

Tags: dle

Здравствуйте!
Требуется cms для рекламно информационного сайта на 15-20 страниц, знакомый веб программист посоветовал попробовать DataLife Engine, сайт должен быть дружен к SEO. Почитав что скорость загрузки сайта влияет на поисковую выдачу проверил сайт dle-news.ru сервисом https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/dfkyYM/dle-news.ru

- Performance grade: 85
- Load time: 1.47 s
- Page size: 668.4 kB
- Requests: 31

Поделитесь пожалуйста своими результатами с указанием вашей CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Скорость загрузки влияет при прочих равных и то не факт. Все мои топовые сайты на работают движках Wordpress, Drupal, Modx. DLE больше подходит под варез, онлайн кино и т.д.